# Nested loop for summation for different values of x and y

Tags: matlab

I am supposed to do a nested loop for summation of 1 to 5 for values of x and y of 1 to 5 and 1 to 4 respectively. I m supposed to present the values as a matrix (4,5). However I cannot print the matrix.

```
for x=1:5
    for y=1:4
        for n=1:5
            Tmat=zeros(5,4)
            T=0;
            T(x,y)=T+((4*T1)/pi)*sin((2*n-1)*((pi*x)/a))/(2*n-1)*sinh((2*n-1)*((pi*y)/a))/sinh((2*n-1)*((pi*b)/a));
            Tmat=T(x,y)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your problem printing the matrix? Not sure what you expect to happen.

Comment: The problem is that you always set `T` to zero, then set a single `T(x,y)`, then set `Tmat` to that single element... You need to pre-allocate *once*, and stop overwriting your matrix with scalars...this is just a mess right now.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. I tried something different now, and it seems to be working.

Comment: @AlikoKinav: Having solved a question yourself, please either write an answer to your own question if you think it is worth sharing or delete the question.

Comment: Hi Daniel I wanted Tmat to show a 4x5 matrix. But it doesn't

Comment: Hi DocRattie, I still can't make the code work even with your edits :/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe this is what you want:

```
T1=1; a=1; b=1;
Tmat=zeros(5,4);
for x=1:5
    for y=1:4
        for n=1:5
            %// Because we're summing, Tmat(x,y) gets increased for each n
            Tmat(x,y)=Tmat(x,y) +  ((4*T1)/pi)*sin((2*n-1)*((pi*x)/a))/(2*n-1)*sinh((2*n-1)*((pi*y)/a))/sinh((2*n-1)*((pi*b)/a));
        end
    end
end
```

Please note, I didn't know your intended values of T1, a, or b, so I put in dummy data.

Comment: Isn't the `Tmat(x,y)+`-part unnecessary as it's always a Zero?

Comment: `Tmat(x,y)` is only zero before the first iteration of `n`.

Comment: But the values are a bit too small, think that might be due to my error in writing the equation